# expected segmentation fault while incrementing NULL pointer

Tags: c

I was expecting the below code to give segmentation fault. Since NULL pointer points to nothing, incrementing something that points to nothing is meaningless.
But its printing 0,4,8,12,16.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *p ,i=0; 
    p = NULL;
    for(i=0;i<5; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",p++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Joe, wrong, reading will also have this effect, no reading is performed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *not* dereferncing `p`, you're converting it's stored *value* to an `int`.  If you where doing:

```
printf("%d\n",*p++);
```

*then* you'd seg fault.

Comment: He might obtain a segmentation fault, but there's no guarantee about what would actually happen.

Comment: There is no conversion in this code. Passing a pointer for a specifier that expects `int` has undefined behavior, not implied conversion. It may happen to behave as if a conversion occurred, but that is not reliable.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` pointers cannot be dereferenced (which you don't do).

Rather, you are passing the pointer to `printf` inside an ellipsis, and printf thinks it is dealing with an integer, implicitly performing an unsafe cast (thus your program is also invoking undefined behaviour).

Comment: It's only undefined if the result of the conversion cannot be represented by the integer, otherwise implementation defined.

Comment: The undefined behavior is already at the `++` operator. This is only allowed for pointers that point to a valid object.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behavior: `++` operator is only allowed for pointers that point to a valid object and in addition you are passing a pointer value to `printf` where the format specifies `int`.

Undefined behavior may result in anything, even that your program seems to work. C doesn't impose any compile time or runtime check for such code. Don't do it.