# char* p=NULL, cout<<p; gives exception

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I was recently asked this question in an interview:

```
char* p = NULL;
cout << p << endl;
++p;
cout << p << endl;
```

I gave the answer that first cout will print 00000, next will print 00001.
But when I checked it in visual studio, it gives an exception:
First-chance exception at 0x009159F1 in StringFunctions.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x009159F1 in StringFunctions.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

But it works as expected for int, float etc.
Could anybody explain this? 
Appreciate the help!

Comment: Undefined Behaviour. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19180731/1462718  and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/394774/1462718  See the "Note that incrementing a pointer that contains a null pointer value strictly is undefined behavior".

Comment: This was not a duplicate of the proposed thread.  While the OP is invoking UB by incrementing a null pointer, he is primarily concerned with how to print the address of a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `char*` overload of `std::cout::operator<<` expects a null-terminated C-string. That's why it's trying to access the pointer.

To bypass this behavior, cast the pointer to `void*` first.

Answer (score 2):

The output stream knows that, when you pass a `char*`, you want to print a string. You passed an uninitialized pointer.  It tried to read it as a C string... and, well, that invoked undefined behavior.

If you want to print an address cast to `void*` first, i.e., `static_cast<void*>(p)`.

As an aside, `NULL` is not guaranteed to evaluate to `0` (in the all `0` bits sense).  It is however guaranteed to compare *equally* to `0`.  Not the same thing.  Also, your increment invokes UB as well.

Comment: Do you have any examples of situations where NULL is not defined as 0? People always say that, yet there is no logical reason to do it.

Comment: @Brett: I have a spec, as you do.  That doesn't mean it won't work in practice, it only means that you shouldn't write code which counts on it if you can avoid it.

Comment: C++ these days recommends using the keyword, nullptr, rather than NULL or 0.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in simplest explanation, cout tries to deference the pointer and print the string because you passed a char pointer

The best way to understand this is following piece of code.

```
char *s = "hello";
cout << s+2 << endl; // Or &s[2]
```

It would output "llo" where as the first hunch would be something like "print address of first l"